# Xamarin forms Emojis is not working in mobile side?

Tags: xamarin.forms, emoji

I am working on a chat application where I can send emojis. No issues when I send emojis, but when I retrieve those emoji messages the REST API is not working. While researching I found need to convert the emojis to Unicode before sending and convert again when retrieve. What is the correct way when working on emojis? I am using Label for showing messages.

I am sending emojis from the mobile side like below screenshot:

[image]

How I can do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a PCL you can do it something like this:

```
  System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(*string*); // Encode
  System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(*string*); // Decode
```